# Можно ли создать отдельный файл (json или xml) с маркерами для Google Maps?

Tags: java, android, json, google-maps-api

Есть ли вариант создать какой-нибудь отдельный массив с Google Maps markers, а не писать что-то вроде этого в onMapReady? (и как не прописывать у маркеров значок, если он у всех будет одинаковый)

```
Marker m1 = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(38.609556, -1.139637))
        .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
        .title("Title1")
        .snippet("Snippet1")
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.logo)));


Marker m2 = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(40.4272414,-3.7020037))
        .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
        .title("Title2")
        .snippet("Snippet2")
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.logo)));


Marker m3 = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(43.2568193,-2.9225534))
        .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
        .title("Title3")
        .snippet("Snippet3")
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.logo)));
```